# Is it possible to use RandomChoice to choose without other choices being evaluated?

Tags: functions, evaluation, random

I'm trying to do this:

```
i1 = 1;
i2 = 1;

RandomChoice[{
  (i1 = i1 + 1),
  (i1 = i1 - 1),
  (i2 = i1 + 1),
  (i2 = i2 - 1)}]
```

In order to chose randomly which variable is going to be incremented or decremented - but it's not working. I've also tried with `--` and `++` but I had the same problem. I am clueless about what may be the problem.

Answer (score 17):

May be the most compact approach:

```
Hold[i1++, i1--, i2++, i2--][[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]]
```

Answer (score 11):

I'd do :

```
choices = {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};
{i1, i1} = {i1, i2} + RandomChoice[choices]
```

Answer (score 11):

Putting `Increment` or `Decrement` in third argument of `Extract`:

> Extract[expr, list, h]
>
> extracts parts of expr, wrapping each of them with head h before evaluation.

```
{i1, i2} = {1,1};
vars = Hold[i1, i2];

Extract[
  vars
  , RandomInteger[{1, Length@vars}]
  , RandomChoice[{Increment, Decrement}]];
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the expressions inside `RandomChoice[list]` are evaluated before one of the elements in the list is picked. You can use the functions `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` to force the evaluation of the elements in the list to occur after the random choice like this:

```
ReleaseHold@RandomChoice[{Hold[i1++], Hold[i1--], Hold[i2++], Hold[i2--]}];
```

Answer (score 8):

There are already many great answers here.  Most of then work by holding various things unevaluated.  I'd like to propose an alternative of sorts.

If we use [indexed Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) we can avoid unwanted premature evaluation without `Hold` or similar.  Working with lists of "keys" is far easier than working with lists of assigned Symbols.

```
i[1] = 1;
i[2] = 1;

i[#@{1, 2}] += #@{-1, 1} & @ RandomChoice
```

That's two calls to `RandomChoice`, compressed with `Function`, one for the list of keys and one for the list of addends.  Generalized:

```
roff[s_, keys_, os_, f_: RandomChoice] := s[f@keys] += f@os
```

Now:

```
i[_] = 1;

Do[
 roff[i, {"a", "b", "c"}, {-7, -3, 2, 4, 6}],
 {50}
]

i /@ {"a", "b", "c"}
```

> ```
> {-7, 9, -3}
> ```

Note that you could use any other sampling function besides `RandomChoice`.

Or taking it in a different direction:

```
sampleApply[s_, keys_, fns_, R_: RandomChoice] := R[fns] @ s[R@keys]

j[_] = 0;

Do[
 sampleApply[j, Range@5, {Increment, Decrement}],
 {100}
]

Array[j, 5]
```

> ```
> {3, -4, 2, 1, -6}
> ```

I hope these examples illustrate the flexibility and convenience of this approach.

Comment: Avoiding Hold induced headache is always good +1

Answer (score 5):

`Switch[RandomInteger[3], 0,++i1, 1,--i1, 2,++i2, _,--i2]`

Answer (score 2):

This is a more general approach, already made to a function: `holdRandomChoice` chooses randomly one of the listed commands without any of the others being evaluated:

```
SetAttributes[holdRandomChoice, HoldAll];
holdRandomChoice[list__] := Module[{x = Unevaluated@list},
   Part[x, RandomInteger@{1, Length@x}]];

Clear[i];
holdRandomChoice[Print[i = 1], Print[i = 2], Print[i = 3]]
i
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[1]:= 2
>
> Out[4]= 2
> ```

Note that none of the other commands got printed.

Comment: FYI: you don't need `Unevaluated` or `Module` here; it would be a bit cleaner to use: `Part[#, RandomInteger@{1, Length@#}] & @ Hold[list]`

Comment: Actually, I would just write: `holdRandomChoice[list__] := ReleaseHold @ RandomChoice @ Thread @ Hold @ {list}`

Answer (score 1):

a variation on tom's answer:

```
ReleaseHold@RandomChoice[{
     Hold[i1 += RandomChoice[{-1,1}]],
     Hold[i2 += RandomChoice[{-1,1}]] }]
```

which may be useful since it can be generalised, eg.:

```
ReleaseHold@RandomChoice[{
     Hold[i1 += RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3]]],
     Hold[i2 += RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3]]]}]
```