# Using a[i] as variables

Tags: variable-definitions

I am using variables of the form $a[i]$, e.g. $(a[1],a[2],a[3],...)$. When I pass them to a function I need to determine which one they are, in other words, what the value of $i$ is.

Specifically, I need to do something like this:

```
a[1]=2.1; a[2]=3.5;
Test[x_]:=Block[{i}, *Some how set i=index value of a[i]*;
Return[{i,a[i]}];
];
```

So that

```
Test[a[1]]
```

returns

```
{1,2.1}
```

and

```
Test[a[2]]
```

returns

```
{2,3.5}
```

Comment: We may need more context to answer this.  Simplistically you could use pattern matching, e.g. `fn[a[n_]] := Row@{"this one is ", n}`.  Somehow I think that you might mean something else however.  Perhaps you are having evaluation problems, e.g. there is an existing definition like `a[1] = 3.2`?

Comment: Are you going to be applying this directly to `a[1]` or `a[2]`? If so `SetAttributes[Test, HoldAll]; Test[a[i_]] := i` would work.  But it won't work in all applications.  E.g. `var = a[2]; Test[var]`.

Comment: How is this useful? How are you going to use it? Seems like `{i, a[i]}` is shorter than `Test[a[i]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I am curious, which part of my answer did you find useful?  If it is the first then I would like to join Michael in asking how you are going to use this.  It may be that you would be better served by keeping `a` and the index (`1` or `2`) separate to begin with.  In fact this is one of the major advantages of using "indexed objects" like this, e.g. [(32202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32202/121).  You might define your `Test` function something like `Test[s_Symbol, i_] := {i, s[i]}` then call it with `Test[a, 1]`.  This does not require any Hold attributes.

Comment: You could also use a [SubValues definition](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121) like `test[s_Symbol][i_] := {i, s[i]}` which would allow `test[a] /@ {1, 2}`.  Finally please consider *not* starting user function names with capital letters as there is risk of collision with built-ins, either now or in a future version.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have developed several lists of data, e.g. x[i][[j,k]], for which the index i has significance. To process the data in needed to know the value of i. I know I could have entered the same data as x[[i,j,k]] but that seemed too ugly to me. So, having already entered it as x[i][[j,k]] I needed your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you need a Hold [Attribute](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html) on your `Test` function and to pass the "symbol" unevaluated:

```
a[1] = 2.1; a[2] = 3.5;

SetAttributes[Test, HoldFirst]

Test[x : _[n_]] := Block[{i}, i = n; {i, x}]   (* Block is superfluous here *)

Test[a[1]]
Test[a[2]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2.1}
>
> {2, 3.5}
> ```

This will *not* let you do something like `Test /@ {a[1], a[2]}` however as e.g. `a[1]` will first evaluate to `2.1` and there is nothing to match.

If you *cannot* pass the argument unevaluated you have a bit of a problem.  I strongly suggest you rethink the design of your program in that case.  However in an effort to be helpful you could attempt a reverse look-up in the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of `a`, assuming you somehow "know" the Symbol name `a`.

```
test2[v_, s_Symbol] :=
 Cases[DownValues[s], (_[s[n_]] :> v) :> {n, v}]

test2[#, a] & /@ {2.1, 3.5}
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2.1}}, {{2, 3.5}}}
> ```